# User Login information store into application in blackberry

Tags: qml

i m developing a blackberry app. in qml and I m storing a user information and use into many pages. how i m storing a user information?

Comment: QSettings for instance, but it depends on the context at large? Please provide more details...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.bbcascades.com/index.php/how-to-s/tutorial-list/50-persistence-of-cascades-memory
see these tutorial and save user data on app